# Создание графической утилиты для выхода из системы (vala)

Tags: linux, vala

Задача такова - написать графическую утилиту, которая позволит выключать, перезагружать и выводить в спящий режим (уже сделано через [*systemctl*](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html)), а также которая сможет заблокировать экран и завершить сессию, не затронув элементы других графических оболочек, тем самым не зависящую от этих самых оболочек.

Насколько я знаю, это всё проводится через dbus или что-то в этом роде. Как именно можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Заблокировать экран и завершить сессию можно через сервис `org.freedesktop.login1`. Выключить и перезагрузить можно через `org.freedesktop.systemd1`.

Установи `qdbus-viewer` и просмотри методы.